# How can I send email from within a script?

Tags: linux, email, gmail

So I have to run huge jobs on a linux computing cluster and I want to write a script that will email me when the jobs finish. I don't care about what the sending email server is, but I want it to send the result to my gmail account. I tried sending it directly via telnet, but I ran into this problem [Sending mail from smtp protocol in telnet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15771932/sending-mail-from-smtp-protocol-in-telnet). I'm thinking that maybe I should send it through my gmail account to my gmail account. But I have no idea how to do this from terminal/within a script. Any ideas?

Comment: no, but wikipedia says it's a windows program. This is all on linux

Comment: If sendmail is installed (it almost always is) you can follow these steps: http://www.simplehelp.net/2008/12/01/how-to-send-email-from-the-linux-command-line/.  Alternatively you can write a php script (hosted anywhere) that will send an email when it is accessed.  Then use wget to access the page when the job completes.

Comment: blat for linux here: http://hgdownload.cse.ucsc.edu/admin/exe/

Comment: Do you want to continue this discussion in chat: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35483/sendmail-discussion

Comment: No thank you, I figured it out. I just didn't read the whole page

Answer (score 1):

You can use [sendmail](http://www.sendmail.org/~ca/email/man/sendmail.html). It is exactly what you are looking for. Here is an [example](http://www.linuxfocus.org/English/May2000/article130.shtml#130lfindex2):

Make a file named test.mail with the following lines:

```
Subject: test local
first line of my message
(compulsory blank line)
```

and do:

```
/usr/bin/sendmail -v your@emailaddress.com < test.mail
```

Answer (score 0):

If the machine is correctly configured to handle email, you could try mailx

```
mailx -s 'Hello World!' email@address.com <<- EOM
this is a test message
EOM
```