# Sending Mail via Telnet

Tags: linux, email, unix, gmail, telnet

I Tried to send email via telnet. But it doesn't accept the data part. The following is the problem occured.

```
$ telnet 74.125.68.109 25
Trying 74.125.68.109...
Connected to 74.125.68.109.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP xr8sm26040278pab.26 - gsmtp

mail from: mohangtrichy@gmail.com
503 5.5.1 EHLO/HELO first. xr8sm26040278pab.26 - gsmtp

mail to: raju10anand@gmail.com
503 5.5.1 EHLO/HELO first. xr8sm26040278pab.26 - gsmtp

data
503 5.5.1 EHLO/HELO first. xr8sm26040278pab.26 - gsmtp
This mail is sent from telnet...
502 5.5.1 Unrecognized command. xr8sm26040278pab.26 - gsmtp
^]
telnet> Connection closed.
$
```

Here what is the problem after data command. Is there any mistake I did. 74.125.68.109 is the mail address of gmail.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15771932/sending-mail-from-smtp-protocol-in-telnet

Answer (score -1):

It's telling you that you aren't saying HELO as your first command.  After each line it's yelling at you again that you didn't say HELO

Comment: After HELO, I tried. But it produce the following error. "530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. q16sm26107597pfi.80 - gsmtp"