# sending email through SMTP without user authentication?

Tags: python, email, authentication, smtp

I'm building a simple app that send you email @ 8:00 AM with your personal weather forecast, now I'm stuck at email sending part, for this I need a SMTP server and it seems that most of the servers require user authentication. Now I thought about just creating gmail account for the app itself but I do plan to open-source it and not sure how can I pass the password safely.

Any suggestion?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9763455/how-to-send-a-mail-directly-to-smtp-server-without-authentication

Comment: Yeah I saw it, but I couldn't really understand it. I can? but how? every smtp I've manage to find and try returns no authentication error

Comment: set up your own smtp service...