# How to send an email on python without authenticating

Tags: python, django, email, smtplib

I'm trying to send a notification from my Django Application everytime the user perform specific actions, i would like to send those notifications from the email of the person who performed these actions.

I don't want them to have to put their password on my application or anything else. I know this is possible because i remember doing this with PHP Long time ago.

Comment: Duplicate of [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9763455/how-to-send-a-mail-directly-to-smtp-server-without-authentication) Also your answer is there.

Comment: Try this api
https://www.mailgun.com/

Answer (score 1):

You connect to the SMTP server, preferably your own, that doesn't require authentication or on which you do have an account, then you create an email that has the users e-mail in the from field, and you just send it.

Which lib you will use to do it, smtplib, some Django stuff, or anything else, is irrelevant. If you want to, you can even skip the SMTP server, and simulate one. That way you can deposit the composed mail directly into users POP server inbox. But there is rarely a need for such extremes.