# Unable to connect to SMTP Server for sending email directly without authentication

Tags: python, email, smtp

I believe that we are able to send email directly to destination MX server such as ('gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com', 25). However I can't connect to the mail server even with socket programming in Python 3.5.1.

```
import socket
with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as sock:
    sock.connect(('gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com', 25))
```

Code above always gives me the following error at line 3.

```
TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
```

I found that people [1] are able to connect to the server stated above, please help me with this issue as I am still clueless about it after hours of research work carried out.

Note that I am running the code on a local computer.

[1]. [How to send a mail directly to SMTP server without authentication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9763455/how-to-send-a-mail-directly-to-smtp-server-without-authentication/29828911#29828911)

Comment: It can be a firewall blocking your access. Can you connect manually using `telnet gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com 25`?

Comment: @Selcuk My firewall program is not turned on from the beginning and I don't have any anti-virus program installed as well. For `telnet`, I get connection timed out issue too. I tried to run the code from my home and working office with no luck neither.

Comment: I can connect just fine using telnet. It is most certainly a network issue on your part. Some ISPs block port 25 to prevent spambots.

Comment: @Selcuk You narrowed down the problem domain for me to tackle, thank you very much :D I am surprised after viewing your profile, you're such a capable person :D